# Hadoop connection refused error after shutting machine down in vmWare , how do I fix this ?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run hadoop on VMware - I had it run last time and was succesfully run command such as

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

but after shut it down and open it again, I got the error :

**[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls
ls: Call From localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:**

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I am new to hadoop and trying to follow the guide line from the link above but still don't get it.

the instruction asking to

1. Check the hostname the client using is correct 
   *=> how exactly ? what command do I use ?*
2. Check the IP address the client is trying to talk to for the hostname is correct.
   *=> can someone tell me which command to use ?*
3. Make sure the destination address in the exception isn't 0.0.0.0 -this means that you haven't actually configured the client with the real address for that
   *=> still don't get how to do this*

I managed to open /etc/hosts and instruction said .. **Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts (Ubuntu is notorious for this)**

what does this exactly mean ? Here below is my hosts file look like ..

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am also getting the ConnectionRefused exception when trying to run hadoop and I also do not understand much from that link.

Comment: Did you get any progress on it?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to start hadoop again? It works :) (VMWare, Ubuntu, single node hadoop)

```
./sbin/start-all
```

As they say on apache wiki and here:
http://iswwwup.com/t/3de851909073/hadoop-connection-refused-in-vmware.html

.. it also confused me, that start-all was not in ./bin folder as they refer here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html